# For loop to increment by decimal

Tags: c++

How can one increment in a for loop such that:

`for (int j = 0; j < 1.0; j+=0.01) {}`

Immediately I know that having a decimal makes the use of `int` odd.

**EDIT:**

Before anybody gets cheeky, I already know `int` is incorrect...the question is how to perform the method since `int` is not a valid manner to do so.

Comment: Why are you using `int` when you need to increment by non-integer amounts?

Comment: You can't do it using an `int`, unless the value indicates hundredths.

Comment: It isn't odd; it is impossible.

Comment: It seems you need to learn about the [fundamental types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) of C++

Comment: Please tell me you know the difference between integers and rational numbers. It is elementary set theory

Comment: So all the comments are exactly what my question is about. I've only ever incremented with `int` (haven't been doing C++ long) so what manner should one increment if a decimal increment is required?

Comment: Use double / float instead of int if you want to work with non-integer amounts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would advise not doing this and use an integer instead.  [Floating point math is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and can give you undesired results.  Using your range for example we could use

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++j)
{
    double step = static_cast<double>(i) / 100;
}
```

This guarantees we get 100 iterations but still allows you to get a decimal "step" for each iteration.

Comment: As so I can use the `step` variable in my loop then for say what I would have used `x = x1 + j(x2-x1)` I just replace `j` with `step`.

Comment: @pasta_sauce Yes.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!

Comment: @pasta_sauce No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Either use `double` and accept the accumulating errors, or use `int` in fixed point form, so you can compute a more accurate value on each loop.

With `double`:

```
for (double j = 0; j < 1.0; j+=0.01) {}
```

With fixed point to get maximum accuracy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    double j = i / 100.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a floating point type instead of an integral type.

```
for (float j = 0; j < 1.0; j+=0.01) {}
```

or

```
for (double j = 0; j < 1.0; j+=0.01) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of `j` is `int`, the result of any arithmetic you do on it will be truncated to an integer value. So those increments will have no effect. If you change the type of `j` to `double` thing will work more like you expect. Keep in mind, though, that 0.01 can't be represented exactly as an IEEE floating-point value (which is what your hardware almost certainly uses).